# ¿Cómo validar un request laravel con Rule::unique con el usuario logeado API utilizando postman?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo una tabla de alerts con su respectivo modelo, los campos permitidos son en el modelo Alert son:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'alert_number', 'alert_custom_id', 'time_at', 'user_id'
];
```

La tabla create_alerts_table tiene las siguientes columnas:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
            ->constrained();
            
        $table->foreignId('alert_custom_id')->nullable()
            ->constrained('alert_customs');

        $table->enum('alert_number', Alert::ALERT_NUMBER);
        $table->time('time_at');
```

Tengo definido aler_number como una constante:

```
const ONE = '1';
const TWO = '2';
const THREE = '3';

const ALERT_NUMBER = [
    self::ONE,
    self::TWO,
    self::THREE,
];
```

En mi método store tengo un request para validar los datos, el problema es el siguiente; cada usuario logeado puede seleccionar tres alarmas pero no puede volver a crear alarma 1, puede editar alarma pero no puede crear dos alarmas 1, de la misma forma puede crear y editar alarma 2 y 3 pero, no puede tener dos alarmas 1 o más.

Así que en el request hice lo siguiente:

```
'alert_number' => 'required',
            Rule::unique('alerts', 'alert_number')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
        }),
```

Dónde aler_number es requerido, reglas de validación es unique en la tabla alerts columna alert_number where user_id es igual al user logeado.

Así impedir que cree dos alarmas con el mismo número.

Al hacer mis pruebas utilizando postman, ya que; esto es una api al inicio todo estaba funcionando bien:

[image: endpoint post alert]

Pero después la regla de validación no funcionaba, asi permitiendo tener dos o más veces alert_number por el mismo usuario:

[image: alert_number repedito]

Pasos que realice para dar solución:

1. ejecutar php artisan cache:config cache:clear route:clear etc.
2. Detener el servidor y volverlo a levantar
3. Cerrar postman y volverlo abrir
4. modificar el código y verificar si hay errores

No entiendo que sucede y cómo solucionar, espero su ayuda por favor

Comment: Podrías poner el código del controlador para darnos una idea completa de lo que estás haciendo? Por otro lado, si vos sabés que esa relación no se puede repetir, deberías crear un índice "unique" en la tabla: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: @azeós el error era que 'alert_number' => [ required etc...] me faltaban los [ ]